# Found multiple elements error in React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Im having a problem with a query, I'm trying to get two radio inputs, I don't have any problem with one of them, but with the other one React Testing Library thrown an error: `It Found multiple elements with the role "radio" and name /to/i:`

### queries

```js
test('Render form with default items', () => {
  const handleUpdateValue = jest.fn();
  const handleNextStep = jest.fn();
  render(
    <Form
      handleNextStep={handleNextStep}
      updateValue={handleUpdateValue}
      transferFundsValues={{}}
    />
  );

  const amountInput = screen.getByLabelText(/amount/i);
  const fromRadio = screen.getByLabelText(/from/i);
  const toRadio = screen.getByLabelText(/to/i);
  const messageInput = screen.getByLabelText(/message/i);

  const continueButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /continue/i });
  const cancelButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /cancel/i });

  // If no value has been entered to the inputs, the continue button must be
  // disabled
  expect(continueButton).toBeDisabled();
});
```

### Html structure

```html
<label for="transferFunds_from" class="ant-form-item-required" title="From">From</label>
<input id="transferFunds_from" type="radio" class="ant-radio-button-input" value="">

<label for="transferFunds_to" class="ant-form-item-required" title="To">To</label>
<input id="transferFunds_to" type="radio" class="ant-radio-button-input" value="">
```

### Error thrown by RTL

```sh
 TestingLibraryElementError: Found multiple elements with the role "radio" and name `/to/i`

    Here are the matching elements:

    <input
      class="ant-radio-button-input"
      id="transferFunds_from"
      type="radio"
      value=""
    />

    <input
      class="ant-radio-button-input"
      id="transferFunds_to"
      type="radio"
      value=""
    />
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong in the HTML structure or if it's a React Testing Library error.

Comment: Are these the full tests? I think we may need a bit more context. Usually you get that error if you try `getByRole` and there's multiple elements, yet I don't see that called anywhere

Comment: @JonathanS. I update my question with the complete test...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 38):

Just a quick tip, if you have multiple matching elements, you can query like this:

HTML:

```html
<a href="/my-element">My element</a>
<a href="/my-element">My element</a>
```

TEST:

```
test('renders my element', () => {
  let link = screen.getAllByText('My element')[0] as HTMLAnchorElement;
  expect(link.href).toContain('/my-element');
});
```

Comment: Is this the best practice or would it be better to use data-testid on original doc and use it on tests when more than 1 element are present?

Comment: You can do that as well, if you prefer.

Comment: Also, in my case I actually wanted to see that there was two instances of what I was searching for. In such a case I used getAllByText('some text').toHaveLength(2)

Answer (score 16):

What was causing this for me was simply having another render() in the test file that was not inside an it().... so the component was being rendered twice.

rookie mistake :-)

Comment: Along similar lines, I ran into this in a test file that had both enzyme and RTL tests. Had to call `wrapper.unmount()` on earlier tests so that there was no extra lingering component by the time my RTL test ran

Answer (score 9):

If you have multiple matching elements try this one

```
<Typography component={"span"}>
  Some text
</Typography>
```

`getAllByText` if more then 1 Matches it`ll return array

Types of Queries Please check the documentation [Summary Table](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/)

```
it('It will display Some text', () => {
    const subTitle = screen.getAllByText(/Some text/i);
    expect(subTitle[0]).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote similar expects and for me works well. Maybe something is wrong with your current `@testing-library/react` version. Try `10.4.9`

The code that I used

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'

function Form() {
  return (
    <div>
      <label
        htmlFor="transferFunds_from"
        className="ant-form-item-required"
        title="From"
      >
        From
      </label>
      <input
        id="transferFunds_from"
        type="radio"
        className="ant-radio-button-input"
        value=""
      />

      <label
        htmlFor="transferFunds_to"
        className="ant-form-item-required"
        title="To"
      >
        To
      </label>
      <input
        id="transferFunds_to"
        type="radio"
        className="ant-radio-button-input"
        value=""
      />
    </div>
  )
}

test('Render form with default items', () => {
  render(<Form />)

  const fromRadio = screen.getByLabelText(/from/i)
  const toRadio = screen.getByLabelText(/to/i)

  expect(fromRadio).toBeVisible()
  expect(toRadio).toBeVisible()
})
```

Comment: I'm using `@testing-library/react: ^11.2.3`. So I need to downgrade to `10.4.9`?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it using string instead of regex:

```
const toRadio = screen.getByLabelText("to");
```

There is some problem with two caracters names in Jest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having multiple tests under it and you have a single render function in the describe then you can try putting that render function inside a beforeEach

```
describe('This is a test section'), () => {

  beforeEach(() => render(<Element {...testProps}/>))

  it('smaller test',() => {
    // actual test
  })
})
```

and then try to run the test. This should solve it. If not then you can try to run the cleanup function and clear all the mocks after each test