# How to filter getByLabelText query when found multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

how to filter the `getByLabelText` query, if It is throwing an error of the type: `TestingLibraryElementError: Found multiple elements with the text of: /to/i`, I have the following HTML structure, which has some nested labels:

### Current HTML structure

```html
<div class="ant-row ant-form-item ant-radio-group-cards" style="row-gap: 0px;">
    <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-label">
        <!-- <label> with "To" text -->
        <label for="transferFunds_to" class="ant-form-item-required" title="To">To</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="ant-col ant-form-item-control">
        <div class="ant-form-item-control-input">
            <div class="ant-form-item-control-input-content">
                <!-- Other <label> with "To" text here -->
                <label class="ant-radio-button-wrapper">
                    <span class="ant-radio-button"><input id="transferFunds_to" type="radio" class="ant-radio-button-input" value="" /><span class="ant-radio-button-inner"></span></span>
                    <span>
                        <li class="ant-list-item">
                            <div class="ant-list-item-meta">
                                <div class="ant-list-item-meta-avatar">
                                    <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" style="font-size: 48px;"></svg>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ant-list-item-meta-content">
                                    <!-- "To" word here inside a label -->
                                    <h4 class="ant-list-item-meta-title">Account to</h4>
                                    <div class="ant-list-item-meta-description">Choose the account to transfer to</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <span role="img" class="anticon icon-size-middle" style="align-self: center;">
                                <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class=""></svg>
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### RTL Test

```js
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';

// query applied
screen.getByLabelText(/to/i);
```

Comment: Does any of these help ? https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/482 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68943625/found-multiple-elements-error-in-react-testing-library

Comment: Thanks for the links but I had already seen both of them and I tried to apply those solutions and it does not work as expected, the test keeps crashing with the same error.

Comment: i'm unable to reproduce the error, could you have a look on https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-easley-doom6, based on your HTML is it returning the input#transferFunds_to, can you fork it and make a reproducible error?

Comment: @oieduardorabelo I create a new one with all the html structure, there u can reproduce the error... I going to update my answer with the complet HTML. https://codesandbox.io/s/trhh8?file=/src/App.js:71-14670

Comment: App.test.js is empty on that link, could you double check you shared it correctly? thank you

Comment: @oieduardorabelo can check again please... I save the changes, If u can see the HTML plase copy it and try with your sandbox I don't know what is happening

Comment: You can't filter the results when using a `getBy*` query as it throws an error when there's anything but a single result. Have you followed the instructions in the error? What do you want to filter by? Or rather, is there something more specific to search by? Which specific element are you trying to target?

Comment: @DrewReese you can check this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/trhh8?file=/src/App.test.js, here in stackoverflow I can't post all the `HTML`, I get an error saying that most of the question is code... so you can see the specific error, the idea is to be able to access the input with the id="transferFunds_to"

Comment: Knowing that nowadays only a few people/websites seem to care about properly structured and semantically maybe even rich and valid HTML markup, the shown html fragment, even in the most forgiving eyes, with its single list item which is nested within a label element, is setting another ***poor quality*** mark. The same accounts for the first occurring label which flows freely without any relation to any form control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for the codesandbox Cristian: https://codesandbox.io/s/trhh8

as you pointed in your question, there is conflicting text matching on both labels

texts "Account to", "Choose the account to transfer to" inside the second label

if you are happy with that, and you don't want to change the html structure, the only available option is to use a more strict regex in your `screen.getByLabelText`

i forked your example and updated the regex to `screen.getByLabelText(/^to$/i)`, and it worked as expected, since all other "to" are followed by or have a space after it, e.g. `" to"` or `"to "`, the label `"To"` doesn't have pre or post space, which fulfills the regex

the final test case is:

```js
import { screen, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

test("case-sensitive To", () => {
  render(<App />);
  expect(screen.getByLabelText(/^to$/i).id).toBe("transferFunds_to");
});
```

have a look on https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-get-by-label-regex-g8tlx

of course, you can also change the API and use a `.querySelector` or more generic JS apis

Answer (score 11):

## Issue

All `getBy*` queries throw an error when there are zero matches or greater than one match.

[Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about)

[image]

The error says you should use one of the `getAllBy*` queries which return an array of matches and only throws an error if no matches are found.

## Solutions

Since you want to target a specific `input` element with `id="transferFunds_to"` attribute you've at least a couple options:

1. Add a `testid` to the input and query by that.

   ```
   <input
     id="transferFunds_to"
     data-testid="transferFunds_to" // <-- add a data test id
     type="radio"
     class="ant-radio-button-input"
     value=""
   />
   ```

   test

   ```
   test("case-sensitive To", () => {
     render(<App />);
     screen.getByTestId("transferFunds_to");
   });
   ```
2. Use a [manual query](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#manual-queries) and target by the specified `id` attribute.

   ```
   test("case-sensitive To", () => {
     const { container } = render(<App />);
     container.querySelector("#transferFunds_to")
   });
   ```

[image: Edit how-to-filter-getbylabeltext-query-when-found-multiple-elements]